# setupTests.js not loading automatically in CRA react app

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, create-react-app, babel-jest

I have read that src/setupTests.js is supposed to load before every test but I still get every test failing with the error:

> "Enzyme Internal Error: Enzyme expects an adapter to be configured, but found none."

this is my src/setupTests.js

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import 'whatwg-fetch';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Here is my package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"coveralls": "^3.0.2",
"enzyme": "^3.7.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.6.0",
"enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.4",
"jest": "^23.6.0",
"react-test-renderer": "^16.5.2",
"redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
"regenerator-runtime": "^0.12.1",
"whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0"
}
```

I am running a "test" script via `npm run test`

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest",
  "test:watch": "jest --watch",
  "test:updateSnapshots": "jest --updateSnapshot"
}
```

I start every test file with some form of the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
```

I am on React 16 with react-scripts 2.1.1

Am I doing anything wrong that anyone can see?

Comment: Did you try restarting the test runner? This is pretty much identical to my working set up.

Comment: @DeveloperDavo I have deleted my node_modules folder and `npm install`ed it multiple times. Does that count as restarting my test runner? What exactly is the test runner in this case?

Comment: Indirectly :). Rerunning `npm run test` (or `npm test`) would do the trick, but I now see the question has already been answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does it work when you add the following to your package.json

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  ...

}
```

Comment: This worked. Any idea why? I guess the "Jest" command bypasses the CRA defaults?

Comment: I believe it is because `react-scripts test` creates a Jest config that would be bypassed by running `jest` instead. Here is the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/3be35763044c690458e806c255e100336de0d9a1/packages/react-scripts/scripts/test.js)

Answer (score 4):

Update package.json.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test setupFile ./src/setupTests.js",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

*I ended up here with the same error but another cause:*

I had a **typo in the file name**:

- `src/setupTest.js` instead `src/setupTest*s*.js`

Then the default CRA (creat-react-app) `package.json` command loads the Adapter into your test:

- `"test": "react-scripts test"`

Comment: you saved me out of an hour debug, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you made the setupTests.js file while in watch mode in create-react-app's `npm test` script, then you need to quit watch mode and restart it for it to begin working.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with this configuration. As same configuration works in my app. Try putting import in test file.

```
import "../setupTests"
```

Sometimes this works.

Comment: I have put a "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile" override in my package.json before and that works but it breaks the vs code debugger because it shouldn't be necessary.