# skip import React from 'react' from test file using jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

I'm using testing-library with react

I have this in my test file

```
import React from 'react' // best if I can skip this in every test file
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
```

but I got this error

```
`@testing-library/react` import should occur before import of `react`
```

either I turn off the eslint rule for order or I can somehow skip doing import React in every single test file.

Answer (score 0):

You can include this information in a `src/setupTests.js` file as follows [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71378709/is-there-a-way-to-predefine-common-imports-for-all-test-files-in-jest):

```
import { React } from 'react';

global.React = React;
```

If the setupTests.js does not run by default, you might need to modify the "test" property under "scripts" (if you are using that to run your test cases):

```json
"test": "react-scripts test"
```

Reference: [setupTests.js not loading automatically in CRA react app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642594/setuptests-js-not-loading-automatically-in-cra-react-app)

Hope this helped.